# How to have textmode for " and "

Tags: text-mode

I am trying to have `"` and `"` for my word but the output:

[image]

and i find this website:

[image]

I try to add
`\usepackage{textmode}`

with using
`$\textquotedblleft$ Strawberry $textquotedblright$`

But it give error below:

[image]

Comment: There is no standard package nemes `textmode`. Whay don't you use the `\enquote` command (package `csquotes`)? You can choose your style of quoting marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only because `textmode` is not a package. Detexify only indicates you that the command `\textquotedblleft` can be used directly in normal text mode. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textquotedblleft Strawberry\textquotedblright
\end{document}
```

gives[image]

Comment: thanks. How to make a space after the `"`? I tried `\textquotedblleft Strawberry\textquotedblright is very sweet.`, but no space after `strawberry` word.

Comment: Just add ``{}`` right after the ``\textquotedblright`` command.

Comment: thanks. i just found `\space` can be used also

Answer (score 7):

Here is how it can be done with  `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{Strawberry Fields Forever}

\setquotestyle{french}
\enquote{La Folle Complainte}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `\textquotedblleft` and `\textquotedblright` for quote marks (or the `csquotes` package for that matter, despite it being very useful in many cases):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
``Strawberry''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. It works well